# Regional Mathematics Olympiad 1999 Question

Tags: elementary-number-theory

find all solutions in integers m,n of the equation (m-n)^2 = 4mn/(m+n-1)

On solving i got, (m + n)[(m + n)/(m - n)^2 - 1] = 0

thus either m = -n or m + n = (m - n)^2

I tried some even odd stuff as m,n are integers but i am stuck now.

Comment: Exactly where are you stuck at?

Comment: we need to find all integer solutions here, i have only found results on m and n

Answer (score 0):

$$(m-n)^2=\frac{4mn}{m+n-1}$$
$$(m-n)(m^2-n^2)-(m-n)^2=0$$
$$(m-n)^2(m+n-1)=0$$

$$m=\pm n$$
$$m=1-n$$

Now substitute for $m$ to reject any cases that dont satisfy the conditions.

Comment: i think the 3rd line of @h-squared answer has a mistake

Comment: I editted that mistake, thanks for highlighting